# Static Library linking Error

Tags: xcode, static-libraries

Getting an Apple Mach-O Librarian Error when trying to archive my project.

I have an Xcode project that links to an FDLibrary. Its a static library contained in the same workspace. FDLibrary links to an SDLibrary. Another static library also contained in the workspace.

I know its unconventional to have multiple static libraries however the SDLibrary contains a lot of common code to several apps while the FDLibrary contains a lot of common code built on the SDLibrary only needed by a few apps. Most basically the FDLibrary contains a lot of specific interface templates while the SDLibrary is almost all data structures and object types.

Building and Running to device works completely fine. But I started to archive today and ran into this error.

All hints welcome! Thanks in advance!

```
Libtool "/Users/rpools1951/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FunDecks-fqrkiylcrromdnbuuyxoyjotckal/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Irregular Verbs/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/FDLibrary.build/Release-iphoneos/FDLibrary.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/libFDLibrary.a" normal armv7s
    cd /Users/rpools1951/Projects/Workspaces/FDLibrary
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only armv7s -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk "-L/Users/rpools1951/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FunDecks-fqrkiylcrromdnbuuyxoyjotckal/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Irregular Verbs/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos" -LSDLibrary -filelist "/Users/rpools1951/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FunDecks-fqrkiylcrromdnbuuyxoyjotckal/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Irregular Verbs/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/FDLibrary.build/Release-iphoneos/FDLibrary.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/FDLibrary.LinkFileList" -ObjC -framework UIKit -lSDLibrary -framework Foundation -o "/Users/rpools1951/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FunDecks-fqrkiylcrromdnbuuyxoyjotckal/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Irregular Verbs/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/FDLibrary.build/Release-iphoneos/FDLibrary.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/libFDLibrary.a"

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lSDLibrary
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lSDLibrary is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```